# About Diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am a self studying student and I am interesting with diophantine equations. I have the following questions:

1. How can I know that a diophantine equation is solved or not?
2. the second question is what is the theory that I need to focus and understand to solve exponential diophantine equations?
   (Please tell me any advise can help me to understand them, books, lectures or any thing).

Comment: For 1, you can try [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/) to see if someone has already asked about it on this or related sites. For 2, the answer is very complicated because of how poorly understood exponential equations are. You are probably best focusing on understanding tools that come into solving examples of such equations which we know how to deal with, like Ramanujan-Nagell, S-unit, or Fermat type equations.

Comment: You should start with understanding and studying Baker's method (for which Baker received the Fields medal in 1970). I recommend his own book: https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511565977

Comment: @Wojowu many thanks.

Comment: @GHfromMO many thanks.

Comment: The answer to 1 is: you cannot know: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem

Comment: @DanielLoughran thanks, but I mean that when I have a diophantine equation,  how do I know this equation is solved before or no it's still unsolved?

Comment: @Wojowu, does approachzero return results from MO? I thought it only searched m.se and AOPS.